# Apple IOS Power Button linkage to activate an app

Tags: ios

I am trying to develop an app which is targeted towards saving time and no. of clicks of a user.

Is there any way by which I can activate the installed app without unlocking the phone by using the power button?

Comment: What do you mean by activating the app without unlocking using the power button? Also none of the installed apps is activated when the user unlocks the phone. All apps that run in the background keep running even with the phone locked.

Comment: Are you wanting to achieve running the application while in sleep mode?

Answer (score 2):

No, thats not possible at all, not even close

The app can be opened when the user press on it, or if another app opens it using a schema.